# Salvage a nice mobile phone to learn embedded programming?

Tags: c, operating-system, embedded, arm

I have a Galaxy S II with a wrecked screen. I was wondering if the internals could be salvaged as a tool to teach myself embedded programming. I know C and enough x86_64 ASM that I would be comfortable taking on ARM assembly.

What would the development environment / set up be like?

Would I use the USB connection or is there a more direct way to connect the phone to the computer?

Would I need to prepare the phone in some way?

Let's say I wanted to write a boot loader for it, are there any good resources of where to start?

Is the phone too much of a black box, should I get a board with more documentation than that?

Or alternatively, why this is a terrible idea. Would all the drivers be too difficult to deal with if I wanted to use things like the camera?

Thanks for the help. I have no idea where to start a project like this.

Comment: Just get a cheap development board

Comment: Must say I'm really surprised at the degree of negative reaction to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ADB ("USB debugging") was turned on, you should be able to do some development by (mis-)using adb and the android ndk to write stand alone executables.  You can also install a more complete arm linux (debian etc) runtime in a chroot.  You could in theory write android apps, and there are ways to trigger them from the adb command line rather than the gui, but so much of android is gui-centric that your interaction with them would be limited.  Still, an app could open a network socket and give you telnet/ssh interaction.

If you don't have ADB enabled you might be able to fastboot (or whatever samsung uses) the device into a customized system image where it is enabled, or even a non-android linux build, but that would depend on having an unlocked bootloader.

Depending on how the screen is broken, you might be able to see enough to turn on ADB, for example backlight problems might be solved by lighting at just the right angle, partial cracking by rotating the device to get the needed menu options in a visible area or even deducing what is on the invisible part of the screen from what is on the visible part and a knowledge of what the menus should look like.

Comment: Thanks. The screen is totally blank, the touch still works. I'll try to mirror along with my new one to get USB debugging turned on. Getting getting a Linux distro on there sounds like the best route. There are also a few screen share programs that let you view the phone (with android) on a computer, I'll give those a shot first.